# Front chainring and Rohloff IGH sprocket not exactly aligned

Tags: internally-geared-hub, chainline, rohloff, bike-friday

I ride a Bike Friday Pocket Llama with a Rohloff internal gear hub. I noticed that the front chainring and the rear sprocket are not exactly aligned.

As the Rohloff internal gear hub will stay the exact same width, I suppose I have to change something about the crank set to get the chain run straight. Any ideas/suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Does the bike work correctly? It's hard to tell (for me anyway) how out of alignment the chain is. As long as the bike pedals smoothly being a little out of alignment is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the chainline will be dictated by the Rohloff IGH.

According to this [crankset guide](https://www.rohloff.de/en/service/handbook/speedhub/assembly/crankset), the Rohloff SPEEDHUB 500/14 requires a chainline of 54mm when using a threaded sprocket and 57mm when using a splined sprocket. So first, you need to confirm which configuration you have.

You can then measure the chainline at the front to confirm how much it is off. This is the distance from the middle of the seat tube to the middle of the chainring. The next picture from Sheldon Brown illustrates it:

[image]

Finally, you need to figure out what is the easiest way to make the chainline adjustments needed at the crankset. For example, depending on your axle/bottom bracket type, there could be ways to add spacers to create the desired offset. You can also replace the crankset for another one with a better chainline.